# force variables from superclass to be assigned (at compile time)

Tags: c#

I have a superclass which has a bunch of variables.
e.g.

```
string s1= ""; string s2= ""; string s3= "";
```

...etc

I'd like to guarantee that these variables get overridden (assigned something useful) in the subclass that inherits from this superclass, at compile time.

is there an elegent way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make all the constructors in the base class take them as parameters, and set them from those constructors:

```
protected BaseClass(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{
    this.s1 = s1;
    this.s2 = s2;
    this.s3 = s3;
}
```

...

```
// Just for example
public DerivedClass(string x) : base("foo", "bar", x)
{
}
```

Hopefully they're private fields anyway, so the derived class couldn't set them directly anyway, right? :)

Comment: Jon, how many "You just bet me to it". comments do you get in a day? Just wondering :) . . .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have virtual fields in C#. If you really need this, you could use Properties which you then override and give a default value in your subclass.

```
public class A
{
  private string s1;
  public virtual string S1
  { 
    get { return this.s1; }
  }
}

public class B : A
{
  private string myString = "default";
  public override string S1
  {
    get
    {
      return this.myString;
    }
  } 
}
```